# Connect By Level In Subquery Slow

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization

I am using a connect_by_level subquery in an Oracle database to supply dates to join with another table.  The connect by level appears to be causing the query to run very slowly.  Here is my slow query:

```
select t.code, d.month_end, count(*)
  from device t,
       (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), - (level - 1)) - 1 MONTH_END
          from dual
        connect by level <= 1) d
 where (d.month_end between t.date and t.exp_date)
 group by t.code, d.month_end
```

The slow query above took about 2 hours to run the other day.  The query below which should be equivalent runs in less than 30 seconds:

```
select t.code, trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - 1 month_end, count(*)
  from device t 
 where ((trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - 1) between t.date and t.exp_date)
 group by t.code
```

Ultimately, I want the 1st query to return data for the past 24 months, but I need to figure out why it is running so slowly with only 1 month as the criteria.  Any suggestions on what is causing the slow completion time with the connect by level query?

Edit to add explain plan output for slow query:

```
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes |         Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                          |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                                |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                          | :TQ10006                 |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,06 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                               |                          |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                                 |                          |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH                              | :TQ10005                 |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,05 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY                            |                          |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN OUTER                         |                          |   520 | 65520 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX RECEIVE                             |                          |   520 | 48880 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          PX SEND HASH                          | :TQ10003                 |   520 | 48880 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 10 |           HASH JOIN OUTER BUFFERED             |                          |   520 | 48880 |   134K  (1)| 00:00:03 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            PX RECEIVE                          |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |             PX SEND HASH                       | :TQ10001                 |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  13 |              NESTED LOOPS                      |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  14 |               NESTED LOOPS                     |                          |   276 | 13800 | 50303   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |                BUFFER SORT                     |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  16 |                 PX RECEIVE                     |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  17 |                  PX SEND BROADCAST             | :TQ10000                 |       |       |            |          |       |       |        | S->P | BROADCAST  |
|  18 |                   VIEW                         |                          |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |
|* 19 |                    CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|  20 |                     FAST DUAL                  |                          |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |
|  21 |                PX PARTITION RANGE ALL          |                          |  3898K|       |  1656   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    75 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|* 22 |                 INDEX RANGE SCAN               | FTR_DT_IX1               |  3898K|       |  1656   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |    75 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 23 |               TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| FTR_DT                   |   276 | 12144 | 50300   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  24 |            PX RECEIVE                          |                          |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  25 |             PX SEND HASH                       | :TQ10002                 |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|  26 |              PX BLOCK ITERATOR                 |                          |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWC |            |
|* 27 |               TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL        | DTL_HIST_DT              |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  28 |         PX RECEIVE                             |                          |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|  29 |          PX SEND HASH                          | :TQ10004                 |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,04 | P->P | HASH       |
|  30 |           PX BLOCK ITERATOR                    |                          |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWC |            |
|* 31 |            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL           | POINT_T                  |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |  

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("C"."CODE"="AP"."CODE"(+) AND "C"."POINT_ID"="AP"."POINT_ID"(+))
  10 - access("CF"."P_ID"="C"."WTN"(+))
  19 - filter(LEVEL<=1)
  22 - access("CF"."DATE"<=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("D"."MONTH_END"))
  23 - filter(UPPER("CF"."PLAN") LIKE '%DV%' AND ("CF"."FT_CODE"='7370' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7371' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7372' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7373' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7374' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7380' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7380C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7381' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7381C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7382' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7382C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7383' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7384' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7409' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7409C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7410' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7410C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='TRKDV') AND 
              "CF"."EXP_DATE">=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("D"."MONTH_END"))
  27 - storage("C"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "C"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
       filter("C"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "C"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
  31 - storage("AP"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "AP"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
       filter("AP"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "AP"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=6)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 8
```

Edit to add explain plan for faster query:

```
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                          |   278 | 33360 |   622K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                       |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                 | :TQ10005                 |   278 | 33360 |   622K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,05 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                      |                          |   278 | 33360 |   622K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                        |                          |  4034 |   472K|   622K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH                     | :TQ10004                 |  4034 |   472K|   622K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,04 | P->P | HASH       |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN OUTER BUFFERED        |                          |  4034 |   472K|   622K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        PX RECEIVE                     |                          |  4034 |   346K|   621K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX SEND HASH                  | :TQ10002                 |  4034 |   346K|   621K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|*  9 |          HASH JOIN OUTER BUFFERED     |                          |  4034 |   346K|   621K  (1)| 00:00:11 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |           PX RECEIVE                  |                          |  2140 | 94160 |   538K  (1)| 00:00:09 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10000                 |  2140 | 94160 |   538K  (1)| 00:00:09 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|  12 |             PX BLOCK ITERATOR         |                          |  2140 | 94160 |   538K  (1)| 00:00:09 |     1 |    75 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|* 13 |              TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| FTR_DT                   |  2140 | 94160 |   538K  (1)| 00:00:09 |     1 |    75 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  14 |           PX RECEIVE                  |                          |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |            PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10001                 |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  16 |             PX BLOCK ITERATOR         |                          |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|* 17 |              TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| DTL_HIST_DT              |  7344K|   308M| 83875   (1)| 00:00:02 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  18 |        PX RECEIVE                     |                          |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  19 |         PX SEND HASH                  | :TQ10003                 |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|  20 |          PX BLOCK ITERATOR            |                          |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|* 21 |           TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | POINT_T                  |   108K|  3376K|   275   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("C"."CODE"="AP"."CODE"(+) AND "C"."POINT_ID"="AP"."POINT_ID"(+))
   9 - access("CF"."P_ID"="C"."WTN"(+))
  13 - storage(UPPER("CF"."PLAN") LIKE '%DV%' AND ("CF"."FT_CODE"='7370' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7371' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7372' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7373' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7374' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7380' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7380C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7381' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7381C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7382' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7382C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7383' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7384' 
              OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7409' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7409C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7410' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7410C' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='TRKDV') AND "CF"."EXP_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "CF"."DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
       filter(UPPER("CF"."PLAN") LIKE '%DV%' AND ("CF"."FT_CODE"='7370' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7371' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7372' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7373' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7374' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7380' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7380C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7381' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='7381C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7382' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7382C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7383' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7384' 
              OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7409' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7409C' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7410' OR "CF"."FT_CODE"='7410C' OR 
              "CF"."FT_CODE"='TRKDV') AND "CF"."EXP_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "CF"."DATE"<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
  17 - storage("C"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "C"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
       filter("C"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "C"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
  21 - storage("AP"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "AP"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
       filter("AP"."EXP_DATE"(+)>=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND "AP"."DATE"(+)<=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=6)
   - automatic DOP: Computed Degree of Parallelism is 8
```

Comment: Can you determine the execution plan for each of the two queries above?  Very likely the change in the query is driving a different decision about access path for the `device` table.

Comment: @Dave Costa - I just ran an explain plan in PL/SQL Developer, but it is my 1st time doing that and I'm not sure how to decipher what it means.  There are some nested loops I see in the slow query that are not present in the faster one along with a table access by local index rowid.  I should also point out the device reference is actually to a view instead of a table.

Comment: @DavidL The best way to get a text explain plan is to run: `explain plan for <SQL statement>;`, and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Post the results here and someone can probably help you interpret the plans.

Comment: @jonearles Thanks for the advice.  I added a text verison of the explain plan output above.  I have done a little research on interpreting explain plans, but still am not clear on what I need to change in my query.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidL, you didn't add complete explain plans, there is no predicate information in these plans, look in this link: http://pastebin.com/mrBF08Br, there is an example how to generate the explain plan on oracle and how the output should look (pay attention to lines 20-23 of this example -> this is "predicate information")

Comment: @korirko - I added the predicate information.  Let me know if you can help explain it.

Answer (score 0):

In first query Oracle is doing an index range scan on a large table and retrieving huge amounts of data on the first pass with `access("CF"."DATE"<=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("D"."MONTH_END")).` You can work around it by rewriting your select to be more like your fast one. It would be something like this -

```
select t.code, trunc(t.exp_date, 'MM') - 1 month_end, count(*)
  from device t 
 where t.date < :report_period_end
   and t.exp_date > :report_period_start
 group by t.code, trunc(t.exp_date,'MM') - 1;
```

Also note that there are several potential problems with your original slow query:

1. A row where t.date and t.exp_date is more than 2 months apart will be counted multiple times.
2. Rows where t.date and t.exp_date has the same month will not be counted at all
3. You are comparing your dates to e.g. 2013.10.30 00:00:00. Results may be incorrect if your dates contain time data.